# Creating python dictionary from pandas dataframe with only unique values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to convert a pandas dataframe to a python dictionary which only has unique values for each key.

I've tried using .to_dict('list') but having trouble getting only unique values.

```
dictionary = dictionary.to_dict('list')


new_dict = {}

for key,value in dictionary.items():
    if value not in new_dict.items():
        new_dict[key] = value
```

Comment: Hey Zachary, can you add in a small sample set of data with intended output. As well as any output you are getting with your current method.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
dictionary = dictionary.drop_duplicates().to_dict('list')
```

You are drop duplicates before to convert to `dict`

---

**Example:**

```
import pandas as pd
dictionary=pd.DataFrame(columns=['list'])
dictionary['list']=[1,2,3,9,4,5,6,7,7,4,3,7,9,'a','b','a','777']
dictionary = dictionary.drop_duplicates().to_dict('list')
print(dictionary)
```

**Output:**

```
{'list': [1, 2, 3, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'a', 'b', '777']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of for loop try rather:

```py
new_dict = {k: list(set(v)) for k,v in dictionary.items()}
```